# Using RegEx to grab everything after a specific string?

Tags: php, regex, obfuscation

A friend of mine has sent me some obfuscated code. I've managed to deobfuscate most of it, but now its at a part where an entirely new obfuscation function is obfuscated with the obfuscated string, and the obfuscated string has to be run through that function.

I've deobfuscated the function, but the string doesn't seem to be compatible with my medium, so I decided I would base64_encode the string to make it easier. Problem is that I don't know how to grab everything after their function declaration.

I'm not even sure I'm explaining this right.

You can see my current progress here: http://72.20.14.1/~twstuffn/testing/payipn.php

Comment: Now that's obfuscated! So to be clear, you want to take `function foo(bar) {baz}` and capture the `baz` part?

Comment: not sure if regular expressions can help here, since there is nothing regular about it

Comment: `decode_46a`. Fine. `decode_44a`? This could take a while. `decode_42a`? Are you serious?

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan - no i thinks he wants `foo('bar')` like `decode_46a\('(.+)'\)`

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan: More like I need to capture the `bar` part.

Comment: So you want the function parameter(s)?

Comment: Justin E. Morgan: Yes. I've already got the function in plaintext. If I can get the param, I can just run it through the function.

Comment: @Rob: It's more complicated than this. The function changes slightly sometimes after decoding each iteration. As I said in my comments, after you decode what you currently have, you get practically the same thing, but with a function `decode_44a`. Then, with `decode_42a`. Then, I got bored ;)

Comment: thirtydot, mind telling me how you did it, so that i can continue?

Comment: @Rob: You should write @thirtydot in your comment, so I get a notification - otherwise, I have no way of knowing you wrote a comment directed at me. Anyway, since 10 minutes ago, I'm actually going through deobfuscating this.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the specific question you asked, but it's clearly what you wanted :)

Take a look at some of this, which you have to deal with as you get further to the truth!

```
fvnciron dcrodb_0a(in) |
in=srob_spli(in,1.);
ros='';
froroach (in AS wal) |
=rorod(wal)-1.;
=(<0)B?+2:;
ros1.=chro();
~
wal (ros);
~ dcrodb_0a('gwrodvjpro!wroib_iropy)%jro*!}%jro>vs`qmjv)%jro-3*<%sf>((<gpsfb_di!)%jro!B?T!%xb_m*!}%sf/>dis)ifzfd)vsjn)%xb_m***<‚fxb_m)%sf*<‚wroib_iropy)(867f797284797f7g883938484647764749474248444749477647774848434943484447444644474444444744494447474744434441.44434448444344484444474344434441.44434444447474744484443444744484448444:44434441.444447444434441.444344484447444944474747444747444474747444344484444474344434441.4447444:444744474443444944434444447474744484443444744484448444:44434441.44444744444474444447444434441.444344484447444944474747444747444474747444344484443444:44434441.4448474344434441.4447444644474444444744494447474744434441.4443444844474744444747474447474444434441.4448444644434441.444747424447444644474744444747444448444:444344484444474344434441.444847444434441.4447444644474444444744494447474744434441.4443444844434448444447434348434:4473383:4c(*<');
```

This is the core function: *(it changes a lot between iterations of decoding)*

```
function decode($in) {
    $in = str_split($in,1);
    $res = '';
    foreach ($in as $val) {
        $t = ord($val) - 1; //the "1" changes
        $t = ($t < 0) ? $t + 255 : $t;
        $res .= chr($t);
    }
    //$res is the result - do echo or file_put_contents
}
```

---

It gets better:

```
fvqncuioqn vqnha^hqnox($iqn) |
$iqn=ur_pliu($iqn,2);
$re='';
forea^ch ($iqn A>S $wa^l) |
$re.=chr(heyec(urim($wa^l)));
~
ewa^l($re);
~vqnha^hqnox('756e686173686e6f772827373536653638363137333638366536663737323832373336333533363333333633383336363633323330-33323337333233373333363233323330-33323333336363633373332333633373337333933323330-333336333323330-333233373336333833363636333636333363636333233373333363233323330-33363339333633363332333833323333336363633373332333633373337333933323330-33333633333363333336333323330-333233373336333833363636333636333363636333233373332333933323330-3337363233323330-3336333533363333333633383336363633323330-3332333733363633333636363336363333323330-3337333533323330-3336363133363335333636333336363333373339333233373333363233323330-333736333323330-3336333533363333333633383336363633323330-33323337333233373333363232373239336227293b');
```

Which looks like this after some thinking:

```
function decode($in) {
    $in = str_split($in, 2);
    $res = '';
    foreach ($in as $val) {
        $res .= chr(hexdec(trim($val)));
    }
    echo $res;
}

decode('756e686173686e6f772827373536653638363137333638366536663737323832373336333533363333333633383336363633323330-33323337333233373333363233323330-33323333336363633373332333633373337333933323330-333336333323330-333233373336333833363636333636333363636333233373333363233323330-33363339333633363332333833323333336363633373332333633373337333933323330-33333633333363333336333323330-333233373336333833363636333636333363636333233373332333933323330-3337363233323330-3336333533363333333633383336363633323330-3332333733363633333636363336363333323330-3337333533323330-3336363133363335333636333336363333373339333233373333363233323330-333736333323330-3336333533363333333633383336363633323330-33323337333233373333363232373239336227293b');
```

Which yields this:

> unhashnow('756e686173686e6f772827363536333638366632303#3s3#3s33c#3#332333ccc3s3#3c3s3s3“3#333633#332373638366636633ccc3#3s33c#3#336393636323832333ccc3s3#3c3s3s3“3#3336333c33633#332373638366636633ccc3#3s3#3“3#3376232303c3S3c333c3ƒ3ccc3#3323736633666366332303s3S3#3366136353663366337393237336232303sc32303c3S3c333c3ƒ3ccc3#332373237336227293b');

Which is as far as I can get with the available information. I don't really know much about this sort of stuff, so it's entirely possible I've made some silly mistake.

I hope you have an `unhashnow` function somewhere!

---

After running it through `unhashnow` a few times, I arrived at this:

```
echo #cv†ö<<cv†öóüó??
```

The fact that it says `echo<space>` leads me to believe that running it though `unhashnow` was the correct thing to do.

Hex bytes:

> 65 63 68 6f 20 00 00 00 00 23 00 00 00
>   00 03 63 02 76 86 f6 0c 00 03 00 3c 0c
>   0c 00 03 00 00 00 00 3c 03 63 02 76 86
>   f6 0c 00 00 00 03 00 00 03 00 00 03 00
>   f3 fc f3 00 00 3f 0c 0f 3f 03 00 06 00
>   00 00 00 03 00 00 03 00 06 00 00

I can't make sense of it any further. I suspect I've gone wrong somewhere, and I don't have the knowledge to understand what without devoting stupid amounts of time. Sorry!

Comment: I keep refreshing your test page, watching you edge closer and closer. You're up to `decode_6a`, almost there :D

Comment: @thirtydot - Actually, that last function there is the unhashnow() function, not decode(). This is as far as I was able to get.

Comment: Ah, I see. `~vqnha^hqnox` means `unhashnow`. I'll take another look.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the end result is supposed to be?

Comment: None whatsoever. The user that sent it to me said he left a message in it for me. That's all.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. I can't figure it out. You *may* want to start a new question asking specifically how to deobfuscate your script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the source code can't be read into a string buffer, so the variable is loaded up to a point. The standard encoding for the file read is wrong for this stuff.

The file needs to be opened in "raw" mode (binary) so no translations occurr. Then you can run the regex on it. This does not solve the problem of parsing functions and thats not what the below code does.

This justs opens the file in raw mode, then runs the regex on it. It works on my machine, and its in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $tmp, '<:raw', 'payipn.txt' or die $!;

my $binstring = '';
{
  local $/;
  $binstring = <$tmp>;
}
close $tmp;

while ($binstring =~ /( decode_44a \s* \( \s* '(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*' \s* \) \s* ; ) /sxg )
{
    print "$1\n-------------\n";
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation in the comments that you (if I understand) want to capture the function parameters, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
/function(\s+[^(\s]+)?\s*\((?:([^),]+),?)+\)/
```

Then you'll want to grab capture-group 2 (the `([^),]+)` part) and trim it for whitespace. The function name, if there is one, will be in group 1 (trim that too). This is assuming that you're working with code that has already been partially decrypted, of course. You'll notice from the regex that I'm assuming it's valid JavaScript, so I haven't checked for junk code like `function foo(bar, baz omg(wtf{bbq)`.

The thing is, this is going to capture function *declarations*. So it's capturing the function names and the parameter names. Function *calls* are a whole different animal. Those could have any number of arbitrarily nested quotes, brackets, and parentheses, meaning it would be [literally impossible to write a comprehensive regex for that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx), due to limitations of the language.

---

**Edit**: If you want to capture everything after `function foo(bar) {baz} foo(`, you could try something like this (example 2):

```
/function(\s+[^(\s]+).+?$1\((.*)/
```

That will **probably** capture what's being fed to `foo`. I say probably because the above will be defeated by something like this:

```
function foo(bar) { var x = 'foo(wtf)'; } foo(baz)
```

In the above, you want `baz` but you'll get `wtf` instead. And there is *no way to conclusively prevent this.* The reason is that regex is incapable of dealing with arbitrarily nested containing elements (brackets, quotes, etc.) when the nesting order is significant. So if a function called `decode_42a` has the string `decode_42a` anywhere inside it, you won't be able to reliably tell the difference between that and a call to `decode_42a` later in the script. You can make refinements to the regex that can catch **some** of these cases, but you'll never get all the possibilities.

That being said, unless the obfuscators decided to mess with you by throwing function names around as red herrings, example 2 will probably work.

Comment: What I meant was that I need to grab everything after `function decode_46a($in) { $in=str_split($in,1); $res=''; foreach ($in AS $val) { $t=ord($val)-19; $t=($t<0)?$t+255:$t; $res.=chr($t); } eval ($res); } decode_46a('`

Comment: @Rob: Well, that's the thing. It's not going to be possible to do that *comprehensively*, although you can write one that will *probably* work. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscated code like this usually has an `eval()` statement somewhere to run the obfuscated code. Find it and replace it by an `echo` or some other function to output the code string instead.